# Drupal7/Search Module & Pagination

Tags: search, paging

1. I am looking for a People directory Search Module.
   Something like what they used on top of the link: http://wws.princeton.edu/directory
2. Also in the link above, they have pagination on the top and 
   bottom of the page.
   In my case when I set the 'Pager' in Drupal Admin, it adds the pagination block to the 
   bottom of the page. How would I move it to the top instead?

Thanks.
Boutros.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided, as stated in [help center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Filter :**

A [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module will do the same with few tweaks on exposed filters

like:
 Name filter operator (starts with) and show all (a-z) characters with link each character accordingly.

**Pagignation :**

You can have pagination on top and bottom by overwriting that views template.
just print `print $pager;` where ever you required.

Its better to not load another modules help for something that can be achieved with small changes. :)

Comment: Thanks @Jeet, I got the Pagination part. I agree with you if I can do something with core better than additional modules. I am new to Drupal.

Comment: @BoutrosAbiChedid, You can approve my answer by ticking the right mark if you find it useful for your question. :)

Comment: can you (@Jeet) elaborate more on the exposed filter. I know this is the way to go, but I am not able to follow your directions. Thanks.